# Q job unsuccessful mahout ssvd

Tags: java, mahout, decomposition, singular

I'm trying to run ssvd on some tfidf-vectors in mahout.  When I run it in Java code as follows (with mahout 0.6 jars), it works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    runSSVDOnSparseVectors(vectorOutputPath
     + "/tfidf-vectors/part-r-00000", ssvdOutputPath, 1, 0, 30000, 1);
}

private static void runSSVDOnSparseVectors(String inputPath, String outputPath, 
                    int rank, int oversampling, int blocks,
                    int reduceTasks) throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    // get number of reduce tasks from config?
    SSVDSolver solver = new SSVDSolver(conf, new Path[] { new Path(
            inputPath) }, new Path(outputPath), blocks, rank, oversampling,
            reduceTasks);
    solver.setcUHalfSigma(true);
    solver.setcVHalfSigma(true);
    solver.run();
}
```

I decided that I wanted to convert it to a bash script and just use the cli command instead, but when I do, I get the following error (tried this on version 0.5 and 0.7, neither worked.  I could try 0.6 but I don't think it's a version thing):

```
[username@hostname lsa]$  $MAHOUT/mahout ssvd -i $H/test_lsa/v_out/tfidf-vectors -o $H/test_lsa/svd_out -k 1 -p 0 -r 30000 -t 1
Running on hadoop, using /usr/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /usr/lib/mahout-distribution-0.7/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
12/07/23 15:00:47 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--abtBlockHeight=[200000], --blockHeight=[30000], --broadcast=[true], --computeU=[true], --computeV=[true], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/path/to/folder/test_lsa/v_out/tfidf-vectors], --minSplitSize=[-1], --outerProdBlockHeight=[30000], --output=[/path/to/folder/test_lsa/svd_out], --oversampling=[0], --pca=[false], --powerIter=[0], --rank=[1], --reduceTasks=[100], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp], --uHalfSigma=[false], --vHalfSigma=[false]}
12/07/23 15:00:49 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 100
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Q job unsuccessful.
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.QJob.run(QJob.java:230)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.SSVDSolver.run(SSVDSolver.java:377)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.SSVDCli.run(SSVDCli.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.SSVDCli.main(SSVDCli.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

I'm running this in distributed mode on a cluster.  I've read that Q job failure can have something to do with block size, but mine is greater than p+k.  I also realize I'm using a ridiculously small input (4 vectors), but like I said, it works in the java code.  I'm mostly baffled as to why it would work in java but not in the CLI.  I'm pretty sure I've got all of the same arguments to the function.  I can always just package up the java code into a jar and put it into the bash script, but that would be pretty hacky...

The log for the job says:

```
2012-07-23 15:00:55,413 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2012-07-23 15:00:55,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@6ce53220
2012-07-23 15:00:55,638 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
2012-07-23 15:00:55,697 ERROR org.apache.mahout.common.IOUtils: new m can't be less than n
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new m can't be less than n
    at     org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.qr.GivensThinSolver.adjust(GivensThinSolver.java:109)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.qr.QRFirstStep.cleanup(QRFirstStep.java:233)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.qr.QRFirstStep.close(QRFirstStep.java:89)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:128)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.QJob$QMapper.cleanup(QJob.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.    apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
2012-07-23 15:00:55,731 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2012-07-23 15:00:55,733 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new m can't be less than n
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.qr.GivensThinSolver.adjust(GivensThinSolver.java:109)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.qr.QRFirstStep.cleanup(QRFirstStep.java:233)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.qr.QRFirstStep.close(QRFirstStep.java:89)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:128)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.QJob$QMapper.cleanup(QJob.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
2012-07-23 15:00:55,736 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: This isn't enough info. This trace is just the client saying that the job failed. You need to post errors from the workers.

Comment: There wasn't any output to the logfiles for the task.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: There would certainly be logs from any Hadoop job, with its own output at least.

Comment: I was wrong before.  I added the information from the logs to the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this was because there were some sequence files in tfidf-vectors that were empty, because I was using too many reducers.  This seems like a bug to me.